# Can't select AMD GPU running Ubuntu

Tags: gpu

I'm currently running Xubuntu 16.04 and I would like to use my 2 GPU's for rendering in Blender. They are currently unused and my CPU is doing all the work. But what have I got my GPU's for anyway?

So, I tried the tutorials here on stack exchange about the GPU setup stuff on Ubuntu.

I got 2x AMD R9 280's, and OpenGL is working like a charm.

But I don't have any other option than the CPU in my Blender settings.

I have to use the Xorg drivers because the official fglrx drivers doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 anymore. They are missing basic stuff like multi monitor support. But video-radeon is working great so this is not an issue. and AMDGPU-PRO is not working at all.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to BSE, did you check your User Preference > System panel?

Comment: Yes I did, http://i.imgur.com/aDZQfJI.png

Comment: Being an AMD user myself, I regret to tell you that AMD and Blender are not best friends, I have the same situation, with some AMD models it's possible, but not for all AMD cards, I'm using CPU myself for this reason.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your OS, I'm on Windows 7, it's just that Blender doesn't get along (yet) with AMD. @Noneatme

Comment: Unbelievable. I switched from 3dsMax WC to Blender in hope for better AMD support (AMD support in 3DsMax is a really great pain.) But this won't work either? Very sad.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean, I switched from 3D Max to Blender recently too (for different reasons) but yeah, Blender GPU would work just fine with any Nvidia with Cuda, but AMD integration is still experimental.

Comment: Ok I see now. Thank you for your help & time. 
What should I do now with my GPU's? Seems like they are not great for rendering and for gaming either...